# Is it possible to modify system stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I would like to alter `sp_helpindex` system procedure, or rather replace it with my version.

The reasons are:

- show index_id
- show included columns
- show filter definition
- show fill factor
- show index sizes
- show heap info as well

Also, interestingly enough my version turned out to be better performing (faster, fewer reads, no cursor).

I tried the following, but none of these worked:

- sp_rename
- alter procedure
- drop procedure

The error `Invalid object name 'sys.sp_helpindex'.`

The only option I can think of right now is just to add a new procedure instead of replacing existing. However, there is one disadvantage. I was hoping that `sp_help` (which in turn calls `sp_helpindex`) would pick up my change seamlessly and as a result everybody who uses Alt+F1 on the server would see the change without changing default SSMS key shortcut on every client.

Comment: Interesting question. Anyway, why does the error refer to `sp_helpindex` and not `sp_helptext`?

Comment: I think this is more suitable to database administrators - http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't modify any system procedure. You can create your own and call it instead; you just have to give it a different `sp_` name, mark it as a system object, and not put it in the `sys` schema.

Oh, and instead of creating your own from scratch, [Kimberly Tripp has constantly been evolving her own version, updated for new features](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/sp_helpindex-rewrites/) and of course you should grab [Kendra Little's sp_BlitzIndex](http://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/). You might find that you don't need to write anything, because plenty of other people have already reinvented that wheel, and done it quite well.

Comment: yes, creating a new proc is the only solution I could think of (as I mentioned in the question). Also, Kimberly's proc is exactly what I started with and realized that it does not meet my requirements, it does not show fill factor, index_id or size. Also, my solution is performing better and less code, easier to maintain as there are no cursors.