# If I alter a system stored procedure, under what scenarios can it revert to the original version?

Tags: sql-server

I use `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` to send alerts. The recipients list is hard-coded in a bunch of places. When I needed to update the recipients list, instead of changing it everywhere I just added some logic at the beginning of `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` to handle the change. (Yes, I know this is bad practice!)

Recently, the server was restarted and the custom logic in `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` disappeared. Nobody modified the sp manually. The system did not have any DR issues recently. What are some reasons this sp could have reverted to its original? Is it possible a Windows update could have caused this sp to revert to the original?

Running SQL Server 2012 SP4.

Comment: Bad practice is an understatement. Fix your process instead of worrying about this.

Comment: This is such a huge red flag. Never alter the system objects. ***Never***. `sp_send_dbmail` has parameters like `@recipients` for a reason. Patcing your server should undo these changes, if I recall correctly, which implies you aren't updating it either...

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19599264/314291)

Comment: @Larnu is it documented somewhere that patching the server would undo these changes?